# How to save scraped data to multiple .csv files

Tags: csv, web-scraping, html-table

I'm trying to scrape the historical data table for a number of funds on the financial times website. The url for one of those funds is: https://markets.ft.com/data/funds/tearsheet/historical?s=LU0526609390:EUR (where LU0526609390:EUR is the ISIN for the fund). I have a list of 40 funds for which I need the historical data for and each fund has its own ISIN but the url always follows the same pattern: [https://markets.ft.com/data/funds/tearsheet/historical?s='ISIN'](https://markets.ft.com/data/funds/tearsheet/historical?s=%27ISIN%27) I then need to save the data for each fund in a separate 'ISIN'.csv file.

I seem to be able to get the data for all the funds using the code below but I'm struggling to export this data in fund specific 'ISIN'.csv files.

Also, the values in the date column seem to repeat twice (i.e. Thursday, September 30, 2021Thu, Sep 30, 2021), and I don't understand why.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv

urls = ['https://markets.ft.com/data/funds/tearsheet/historical?s=LU0526609390:EUR', 'https://markets.ft.com/data/funds/tearsheet/historical?s=IE00BHBX0Z19:EUR', '......']


for url in urls:
    html = requests.get(url).content
    df_list = pd.read_html(html)
    df = df_list[-1]
    print(df)
    df.to_csv('my data.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For saving to files, each with a different filename of the ISIN, you could split the url on the '=' sign and select the last entry in the split list which would give the ISIN. The colon is not allowed in filenames, so I've replaced it with an underscore here.

```
ISIN = url.split('=')[-1].replace(':', '_')
df.to_csv(ISIN + '.csv')
```

There appears to be two versions of the date on the website for different sized browsers. You are scraping both of them.

```
<span class="mod-ui-hide-small-below">Tuesday, September 21, 2021</span>
<span class="mod-ui-hide-medium-above">Tue, Sep 21, 2021</span>
```

One way you could reformat the dates is to write a function that will sort out the formatting. This splits the dates by a comma and appends the month/date to the year. I've also removed a whitespace from in front of the month with [1:].

```
def format_date(date):
    date = date.split(',')[-2][1:] + date.split(',')[-1]

    return pd.Series({'Date': date})
```

Then add this to the for loop to perform the function on the date column.

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(format_date)
```

This gives dates in a format like this:

```
Oct 01 2021
```